# linux + cant run dialog utility + got errors

Tags: linux, opensuse, libraries, dialog

Linux kernel: 3.0.13-0.27-default #1 SMP

I’ve installed “dialog” utility ( /usr/bin/dialog ) just copied bin file to /usr/bin

When I have tried to run it, error message regarding missing libncursesw.so.5 lib appeared.

to solve the problem I try to copied the file libncursesw.so.5  to /usr/lib/ 
but not help

•   Now, I got another error:

```
     “error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.5: file too short”…
```

Comment: Try reinstalling package containing libcurses `rpm -qf /usr/lib/ncursesew.so.5`

Answer (score 0):

The `dialog` binary you copied is a dynamic executable, which means that it relies on shared libraries as part of its execution. You can see this with `ldd`:

```
$ ldd "$(type -p dialog)"
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff54fb1000)
    libncursesw.so.5 => /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.5 (0x00007fbc0ecee000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fbc0e9eb000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbc0e640000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbc0ef4d000)
```

In my case, these are the libraries that it relies on. Depending on your version, compilation options, and other factors, your binary may have different requirements.

Since you manually copied the binary to `/usr/bin` without doing any dependency resolution, it is quite possible that these shared libraries do not exist on your system. The second error message you got, "file too short", indicates that something is wrong with that library (probably indeed it is too short, it should be a symlink instead of a file. It's not possible to tell what you put there from your question alone).

Instead of going down this path, you should first try installing `dialog` from your package manager instead of just copying it to `/usr/bin` directly -- that way, you keep a record of the installation of the package, you receive updates without much hassle, and you will have the dependencies for it installed automatically by your package manager. Since you are on OpenSUSE, try removing the files that you manually copied over (`/usr/bin/dialog` and `/usr/lib/libncursesw.so.5`), and then running `yum install dialog`. This should fix all of your problems.